Out of Bound Exceptions
Please help me to solve the problem in selenium
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [0, -1) out of bounds for length 7
code :
package adipolipkg;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

public class Simple {
    EdgeDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void men() {
        driver=new EdgeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.bmw.in/en/index.html");
    }

    @Test
    public void sin () {
        driver.quit();
    }
}

i am adding the screenshot here
Package and code
error screenshot
i need to solve this problem for run the selenium in eclipse and run the edge or chrome driver

I'm not familiar with Selenium but the stack trace shows that the problem is caused by the EdgeDriver constructor. It is trying to get a substring using the negative number -1 as the end index, which is invalid. I don't know what string the EdgeDriver is trying to use, but I guess it's from some configuration variable. I hope that's enough info for you to give you some clue.

Looking at the Java test in the Selenium Github repository, they have @After for the driver.quit() method and not @Test.

I would suggest you avoid trying to Unit Test Selenium. Their developers have already done that. Just use it in your projects. If you want to see their test, go to https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/tree/trunk/examples/java/src/test/java/dev/selenium.

@SedJ601 Don't think OP is trying to test Selenium. This is just a [mre].

@thensage Could you please [edit] your question and add the stacktrace as text? See Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@Sören, If that's the case, it's a terrible MRE. The Main method is the way to go to keep down confusion.

When using a library that's primarily used for testing? Feel free to be confused, but you're the only one.

@Sören, I think you are confused. If I see code in a Unit Test, I am going to assume you are trying to test the code. I don't know how you don't understand that. You are assuming the OP is not trying to test the code. Anyway, the OP's error is most likely due to incorrectly setting things up in the test environment.

I tried with ChromeDriver and didn't get any error. However, I changed some parts of the code. In your screenshot, I saw you are working with JUnit 5. So, in Junit 5, there is no Before but BeforeEach.
There is a precondition that you have to observe. Download ChromeDriver or Edge driver before you run this code.
public class Simple {
  WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.get("https://www.bmw.in/en/index.html");
  }

  @Test
  public void testOpenBMWHomePage() {
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + title);
  }

  @AfterEach
  public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
  }
}

In Maven also you should have:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

